# Pyinstaller generating difference executable sizes on two difference laptops

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a Python project that is converted to an executable using pyinstaller.

The same executable is generated on another laptop and the size of the executable is not the same.

The version of python on both Windows laptops is same. The list of python plugins is the same on both Windows laptops.

The comparison of the file, Analysis-00.toc, an output of pyinstaller, shows the same Python dlls, such as \Python311\DLLS_queue.pyd.

In Analysis-00.toc, the versions of api-ms-win-crt-xxx.dll files are the same, but are not from the same directory. All versions are api-ms-win-crt-xxx-11-1-0.dll. One set is from Java JDK, the other is from Java JRE.

Other than the differences of the directory of api-ms-win-crt, I cannot find any differences between the Windows laptops to explain the differences in the executable size.

Where else should I look for differences that can explain the differences in executable size?

Comment: What is the size difference?

Comment: 11K in 12MB. In examining the differences in the EXE, the first half (about) is the same, the second half is different.

Comment: From memory alone, Pyinstaller works by bundling an interpreter with your script, there's a special type of compiler used for reproducable builds, normally a built executable isn't guaranteed to be the same. 11k is really small, Do you know offhand if as part of it's process it's compiling anything, maybe some weird package but I don't think so off hand, would need to look into it to say anything?

Comment: No I don't know if anything is being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The differences were found out to be that the PATH environment variables was not the same on the two laptops.

Once a set PATH statement was added to the PyInstaller build batch file the EXEs are the same size.

Now the two builds are as identical as a Windows EXE compare can be.